# JSON decode error when trying search through JSON file via FAST Api

Tags: python, json, fastapi

raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

is the error I am getting when I run the following code:

```
read = open('sample.json')
@app.get("/key/{hole}", status_code=200)
def fetch_message(*, hole: int): 
    data = json.load(read)
    for i in data:
     if i['id'] == hole:
        return(i['message'])
        break
```

My json file looks something like this:

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "John Doe",
    "message": "Hello World!"
}
```

Comment: The error you provided indicates that the file (`sample.json`) doesn't contain any data.

Are you sure this is the right file in the right directory that you are trying to access?

Comment: Yes, I am sure that that sample.json contains the data I've mentioned in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to iterate through the keys of the single entry in your json data. I believe what you want is to iterate through a list of entries of json data so your sample.json should be like this instead:

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "John Doe",
        "message": "Hello World!"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are tring to iterate over json, clearly that couldn't go well.

This version work with a file containing 1 json object, like yours.

```py
read = open('sample.json')
@app.get("/key/{hole}", status_code=200)
def fetch_message(*, hole: int): 
    data = json.load(read)
    if data['id'] == hole:
        return(data['message'])
        break  # this is not reacheable
```